# Trying to get text from class having same class for 50 elements..getting List out of index error

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to extract text from an element having  class name or div same as other 50 elements in page.
While trying to navigate it shows error as list index out of range error.

Any help what should I follow to extarct the text from //pclass?

My Code :
elements= driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Untitled Export Job_MDM')]")
elements[0].text

Please see HTML in comment section

Comment: <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 relative"><p class="placeholder text-label overflow-text name-field">Untitled Export Job_MDM 06142020_18:09_HCP</p><label class="label dark-label list-name-label hidden-label placeholder">Untitled Export Job_MDM 06142020_18:09_HCP</label></div>

Comment: Post your full code that is responsible for the said error.